# PostegreSQL Combine columns and convert to timestamp with local time zone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm creating a time slot table in Rails with PostegreSQL that contains columns like

```
slots    
name | type
-----|-----
day  | date
hour | int
min  | int
```

hour would be like 11, 12, 13, 14 ...

min would be like 0, 5, 10, 15 ...

I'm trying to use these three columns and create a timestamp in order to compare against `Time.now` to pull records that's upcoming in the future.

Since PG's `to_timestamp` function creates timestamp with UTC as default timezone, I want to create time from the three columns to use server's timezone and my attempt is below.

```
Slot.select("
     to_timestamp(
       concat_ws(
         ' ', 
         day::text, 
         concat_ws(
           ':', 
           hour::text, 
           min::text), 
           '#{Time.now.zone}'), 
       'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI (TZ)') 
     AS t")
```

And it gives me the error:

**PG::FeatureNotSupported: ERROR:  "TZ"/"tz"/"OF" format patterns are not supported in to_date**

Any suggestions or thoughts would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `to_timestamp()` function returns a `timestamp with time zone` value. If you do not explicitly specify a time zone, then the time zone of the server is used. That seems to be all that you need, so you can safely forget about specifying anything beyond the simple date and time.

Seeing what you are trying to do, however, it would be much easier to use [the `make_time()` function and add the resulting `time` to the day `date` to get the `timestamp`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html) you need. This saves you lots of conversions to `text` and then back to a `timestamp`:

```
Slot.select("day + make_time(hour, min, 0.0::float) AS t");
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm somehow getting an error saying that "PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  function make_time(character varying, integer, numeric) does not exist"

Comment: You hour column is of `int` type so that is very surprising. Did you quote or cast it somewhere? I added a cast to the seconds constant.

Comment: It turns out that I set hour as `t.string` in migration file which I didn't even notice. It's working perfectly now, thanks @Patrick